# Magento 2 : Difference between getRowTotal() or getRowTotalIncTax()

Tags: magento2, price, sales-order, multistore, order-email

In order confirmation email,

I have found these two methods

```
$_item->getRowTotal() & $_item->getRowTotalIncTax()
```

The `$_item->getRowTotal()` seems like

**Row Total = ((ordered item price * ordered item qty) + Tax) - Discount**

But i am not sure about it

Can you please add some details on it
which method to use when & its description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getRowTotal()** including:

> $rowTotal = $rowTotalInclTax - $rowTax;

While **getRowTotalInclTax()** including:

> $rowTotalInclTax = $priceInclTax * $quantity;

For more details you can see the differences here

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/2578

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/2579

Hope this will help you!

Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @devhs Welcome Brother!